# retrieve a hashtable value that was populated as an array

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable

I have a hashtable where the value of each key is populated as a double arraylist. 
Now I wish to retrieve the value of a key (which is an array list) and set it equal to a double array. I tried the following but it didnt work:

```
double[] arrayName;
arrayName = hashtableName.get(keyName).toArray(arrayName);
```

Any idea how to fix this? thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Fix what? How didn't it work? Are you getting an error at compile- or run-time that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: Without knowing your exact errormessage try this: `double[] arrayName = new double[0];`

Comment: Just to clarify, you are assigning an array to `arrayname` not "set it equal to". Without knowing what your error is I'd say you may want to try typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Make sure to use `Double` instead of `double`.

```
Double[] arrayName = hashtableName.get(keyName).toArray(new Double[hashtableName.get(keyName).size()]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double[] arrayName = new Double[4];
    HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Double>> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer,   ArrayList<Double>>(); 
    ArrayList<Double> l = new ArrayList<Double>();
    l.add(2.);
    l.add(3.);

    hashmap.put(1, l);

    arrayName = hashmap.get(1).toArray(arrayName);
    System.out.println(arrayName[0]);
}
```

Use Double and not double here. You can't use the primitive type.